# Running R batch script in a bash script

Tags: bash, r

I am trying to run a batch script (set of R commands saved in a file), from a bash script. For some reason, the statement in the bash script that runs the R script works when I type it manually on the command line, however when the statement is executed in the batch script it fails with the error:

**munge_data.sh: line 17: --file=stats.R: command not found**

Here is a snippet of the bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPTDIR=/path/to/some/directory
RBIN=`which R`

cd $SCRIPTDIR

$RBIN --file=stats.R > my.stats.output.txt # <- this is line 17 in my script
```

Can anyone spot what is causing this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apprently, `which R` returned nothing, probably because R is not in your PATH, so that `$RBIN` is empty, and the shell tries to run an inexistent command `--file=stats.R`.

(If R is supposed to be in the PATH, you can just call it `R`, without using a variable.)

Comment: Hmmm, thats interesting, I am running the bash script from a cron task.; I tested the statements on the command line whilst writing the (bash) script and WHICH R does return the bath to the R binary. As a matter of fact, R is on my path but when running as a cron task, I noticed R was not being found, and thats why I explicitly stated where to find R - and that still appears not to be working - what to do?!

Comment: The PATH used by crontab is defined in the crontab file itself and is usually very conservative (i.e., almost empty). You can either add the directory containing R to this PATH, or change the PATH at the begining of your script (preferred), or hardcode the path to the R executable in your script (e.g., by explicitly setting the value of your `RBIN` variable).

Comment: Yup, the explicit path fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You don't put the right R call function in Bash.

Running R in command line following below command format (R CMD BATCH file output.file)

```
#!/bin/bash

R CMD BATCH your_file.R my.stats.output.txt
```

will get you 99% what you want(Make sure you have execute permission of this bash file)

The reason you didn't get it right is because when execute `which R` ,the control was transfer from bash file to R program , then the bash script pause the execution .

Answer (score 1):

Nobody mentioned Rscript (comes with R) or [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) which predates it:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

z <- rnorm(5)
# ... other R commands ...
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/r  

z <- rnorm(5)
# ... other R commands ...
```

both of which you can run directly once you do the usual `chmod 755 filename`.